# Creating an empty Asp.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2022

I was trying to create an empty MVC project in VS 2022 but I couldn't find true project type. When I chose "Asp.NET Web Application (Model-View-Controller)", it wasn't empty. When I chose "Asp.NET Web Application", it wasn't a MVC project. Which project type should I  choose to create an empty MVC project?

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022 Installer, below the ".NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack", there is a component named ".NET Framework project and item templates" and by default, this component was not selected.
selected and installed it.

Answer (score 2):

You have hit two correct choices.
As said in the projects' descriptions, the *ASP .NET Web App Empty* really is empty and you need to implement MVC yourself.
The default *Asp.NET Web Application (Model-View-Controller)* project includes example Views and Controllers, which you can always delete or modify if want to.

[image]